# jQuery - Photo gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, photo-gallery

Would somebody be so kind and tell me, why this script only works in Firefox and not in Chrome.
Script: when it is finished it should be a simple Photo gallery
Thank you for your help!!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            function animate()
            $( ".picture" ).delay( 2000 ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.00, function() {
                    $( ".picture2" ).animate({ opacity: 1.00 }, "slow" );
                    $( ".picture2" ).delay( 2000 ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.00, function() {
                        $( ".picture" ).animate({ opacity: 1.00 }, "slow" );
                        animate();
                });
            });
            animate();
        });
```

Comment: `function animate()` has no `{..}`? With the above code you must be getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: So you have some minimal complementary HTML? Also, state the JQuery version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the hole html code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <title>Bilderreihe | unfertig</title>
        <style type="text/css">

            .picture {
                position: absolute;
                left: 50px;
                margin-top: 5%;
                margin-left: 30%;
            }

            .picture2 {
                position: absolute;
                left: 50px;
                margin-top: 5%;
                margin-left: 30%;
                opacity: 0.0;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="all">
        <div class="picture">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYtvxXpYfat_I3XYW8tWZ42KJIHR25DsOIgA6CdHVbOXJYHHvDZw" height="300" width="500">
        </div>

        <div class="picture2">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQTIJMikQdg1bqI9PBgD_gBZSTcBCSRvzEN_sj_ngu0TrVbOdtr" height="300" width="500">
        </div>

        <div class="picture3">
            <img src="">

                <button id="left">&laquo;</button>
                <button id="right">&raquo;</button>
    </div>
    <script>



        $(document).ready(function() {
            function animate()
            $( ".picture" ).delay( 2000 ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.00, function() {
                    $( ".picture2" ).animate({ opacity: 1.00 }, "slow" );
                    $( ".picture2" ).delay( 2000 ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.00, function() {
                        $( ".picture" ).animate({ opacity: 1.00 }, "slow" );
                        animate();
                });
            });
            animate();
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```